# Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.NotBoundException

Tags: java, rmi

i have problem that when i run my rmi server i got an exception notbound exception 
even i export the remote object and bind it to registry
 here is my remote interface code

```
 import java.rmi.Remote;
    public interface fact extends Remote {
    public int factory(int a);
    }
```

and here the interface implementation

```
public class factimport implements fact {

    @Override
    public int factory(int a) {
        int mult=1;
        for (int i=1;i<=a;i++)
            mult=mult*i;
        return mult;
    }

}
```

and server code

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;


public class Server extends UnicastRemoteObject {
/**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected Server() throws RemoteException {
        super();

    }

public static void main() throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException{
    factimport fi=new factimport();
    Registry reg=LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
    reg.rebind("factobject", exportObject(fi));
    System.out.println("server started");
}
}
```

and client

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;


public class Client {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws NotBoundException 
     * @throws RemoteException 
     * @throws MalformedURLException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Registry reg=LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1",1099);
    factimport x=(factimport)reg.lookup("factobject");
    System.out.println(x.factory(5));

}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Unless you're running the server and client on the same host, which makes RMI pretty pointless, your `getRegistry()` call in the client needs to be modified to point to the server host, not the client host (itself).
2. Your remote method must be declared to throw `RemoteException` in the remote interface.
3. Unless you have run `rmic` on the remote interface, which you can't have done or you would have detected (2), you need to change the `exportObject()` call to `exportObject(fi, 0),` for reasons explained in the preamble to the Javadoc for `UnicastRemoteObject.`
4. Your `Server.main()` method doesn't have a correct signature so it won't execute. It should be `public static void main(String[] args) ...`
5. You should make the `Registry reg` variable in the server static to prevent it from being garbage-collected.
6. In your client, your variable of type `factimport` should be of type `fact`, and you should cast the lookup result to `fact.`
7. If the `BindException` was really the result of running this code in this state on a single machine, it can only mean that you ignored runtime exceptions when starting the server.

Comment: I bet he is running both on the same computer. This is, quite obviously, just an experiment to learn RMI programming, and there are no real applications yet.

Comment: i know there is no real application when running it on same machine but its just my first rmi example

Comment: my question is that the client cant find the object in registry and i can figure it out where is the error

Comment: You seem to have completely overlooked at least three separate compilation and execution problems in the server. See edit. If your server doesn't compile and execute, how can you expect the lookup to possibly succeed?

Comment: how i can make getregistry to point to server reg??

Comment: Change `"127.0.0.1"` to the server's hostname or IP address.

Comment: i m sry but i m on same machine so host name is localhost

Comment: i added this but i get another exception instead of notbound exception getRegistry("rmi://127.0.0.1/factobject",1099)

Comment: and i also tried to use server static reg in client  to lockup for remote object

Comment: @Tony 1. *Unless you're running the server and client on the same host,* your `getRegistry()` call has to be modified. As you are doing that, you don't have to change the hostname. 2. If you're now getting *another* exception, you must tell us what it is. Otherwise you can't expect any help. 3. You need to pay attention to all the other points enumerated in my answer first. Your code worked for me once I did that.

Comment: @Tony Where did you get `getRegistry("rmi://127.0.0.1/factobject",1099)` from? Not from me. It is hopelessly incorrect.

Comment: @EJP  i dont know how to point to server reg i tried this "rmi://localhost/factobject" in getregistry and i used server static reg but i get UnknownHostException

Comment: no i was watching video tutorial about rmi and they used it

Comment: @Tony You don't need to change it. I've said that twice. `127.0.0.1` is fine if the server is on the same host. What you changed it to is complete nonsense. It's a Naming.lookup() string, not a LocateRegistry.getRegistry() string. Change it back. Fix points 1-7 above and it will work. I can't help you if you're just going to shove in random changes from arbitrary other places and then just state here that they don't work. Nobody here said they would.

Answer (score -2):

Your code is a little unorthodox. I don't know if this will help, but it might.

Normally, the *remote object implementation* would extend `UnicastRemoteObject`. So, you have this `factimport` class:

```
public class factimport implements fact extends UnicastRemoteObject {

    @Override
    public int factory(int a) {
        int mult=1;
        for (int i=1;i<=a;i++)
            mult=mult*i;
        return mult;
    }

}
```

And the server class:

```
public class Server {
/**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected Server() throws RemoteException {
        super();

    }

public static void main() throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException{
    factimport fi=new factimport();
    Registry reg=LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
    reg.rebind("factobject", fi);
    System.out.println("server started");
}
}
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: i m sry but its didnt help same error

Comment: i think i need to exportobject to registry too but i dont know how to do it with ur edit

Comment: 1. The OP is already exporting the remote object, via `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject().` 2. The constructor for `Server` doesn't need to throw `RemoteException,` or indeed even exist. 3. None of this has anything to do with `BindException.` -1

Comment: @Tony There is no such thing as 'exportObject to registry'.